# I have a column in sql which takes multivable values like "1,2,3" based on the multiselect option from front end.

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a multiselect dropdown where in i can select many options and the value of the dropdown gets saved in database as "2,4,6" , if three options are selected from dropdown.Now while retrieving from database , I need the names for the dropdown that is 2 has name as "test", 4 as "test2" in different table . How do i get that in sql query

Comment: Don't save comma separated values in a single column. That is a bad design. Use a proper 1:m relationship

Comment: but it has to be done that way so how to do that

Comment: so your table structure

Comment: the column is a varchar which accepts multiple values

Comment: That is ok. In your question ` different table ` what is that `test` and `test2` store in which table show your table structure

Comment: "but it has to be done that way" - Why? What difference does it make for the end user how you store the values in your database?

Comment: i have a multiselect dropdown suppose i select Chennai,Bangalore,Mumbai then in db the column should save as values for the cities like 1 for chennai based on the city table. So it has to save like '1,5,7' in db . Now how to retrive the citynames from city table